# Uso da função summarySE para construção de gráfico em ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, summary

Olá, busco um auxílio para aprimorar um script em R. Desenvolvo ele com o auxílio do pacote ggplot2. Tenho alguns erros e gostaria de opiniões. No estudo, avalio o efeito da interação intra e interespecífica entre duas espécies de girinos com duas classes de tamanho "p" e "g" no uso de recurso espacial através de duas variáveis resposta: deslocamento vertical(seg) e deslocamento horizontal (cm).

Erros:

- Na execução da função summarySE: "/Warning message:In qt(conf.interval/2 + 0.5, datac$N - 1) : NaNs produced"
- Na execução de legend.title=element_blank():
  Error: unexpected symbol in:"legend.title=element_blank()    legend.title"

segue o script

```
#Importar dados. Pacotes para o gráfico
pmed<-read.table("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cET5cROSb-_D-cZYud3yKBHGR-qamind",header=T, sep=',') 
require(Rmisc)
require(ggplot2)
require(EnvStats)
require(sciplot)
require(dplyr)
summarypmed <- summarySE(pmed, measurevar="PV", groupvars=c("ID","INT"),na.rm=T)
# gráfico 1
                graf1 <- ggplot(summarypmed, aes(x=INT, y= PV, fill=INT)+ facet_wrap(~INT) +  
                geom_dotplot(binwidth=0.05,binaxis="y",stackdir = "center") +                  
                geom_errorbar(aes (ymin=PV.y-se,ymax=PV.y+se),width = 0.25,size=0.25)+         
                  xlab("Tratamentos") +                  
                  ylab(" Posição Vertical (cm)") +                  
                  geom_text(aes(label = paste("N", "==",N,sep = "")), 
                                              parse = TRUE, y=-0.15) +
                  geom_point(aes(y=PV.y), size=1,show.legend = F) +
                  theme_bw () +                  
                  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey85","grey30")) +     
                    theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),                          
                    axis.title.x=element_blank(),                    
                    axis.text=element_text(size=7),                    
                    axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),                    
                    axis.text.x=element_blank(),                    
                    axis.title.y=element_text(size=11),                    
                    plot.title=element_text(size=12, hjust = 0.5),                    
                    panel.grid=element_blank(),                    
                    plot.title=element_text(vjust=2),     
                    legend.title=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este problema não tem solução com o conjunto de dados fornecido. O help da função `summarySE` diz o seguinte (grifos meus):

> Gives count, mean, **standard deviation**, **standard error of the mean**, and **confidence interval** (default 95%).

As três medidas que destaquei acima são medidas de dispersão ou variabilidade. Todas estas três são medidas que dependem da variância amostral. A fórmula da variância amostral é dada por

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o somatório é dividido por *n-1*. Portanto, para que consigamos medir a variabilidade em um conjunto de dados, precisamos de pelo menos duas observações. Afinal, se *n=1*, teremos uma divisão por zero.

Na tua pergunta original, ao agrupar os dados por ID (`groupvars=c("ID","INT"`), tu está dizendo que quer calcular a variabilidade por ID dos sujeitos. Mas veja o seguinte código, em que conto o número de sujeitos por ID:

```
library(dplyr)
pmed %>%
  select(ID) %>%
  count()
 ID freq
  1    2
  2    2
  3    2
  4    2
  5    2
  6    1
  7    1
  8    2
  9    1
 10    2
 11    2
 12    2
 13    2
 15    2
 16    1
 17    1
 18    1
 19    1
 20    1
 21    1
 22    1
 23    1
 24    1
 25    1
 26    1
 27    1
 29    1
 30    1
```

Muitas ID possuem apenas um sujeito. Portanto, é impossível calcular uma medida de variabilidade nestes casos, pois faltam dados. Por isso tu recebeu um warning a respeito dos `NaN` (sigla para ***N**ot **a** **N**umber*) que são criados.